# Getting 'java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection' while connecting oracle database

Tags: java, jenkins, automation, pipeline, rest-assured

I'm facing oracle database connectivity issue while running my automation script thru jenkins pipleline whereas it is working fine when I run the script in local.

**Error Log:**
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: *********: Name or service not known

After googling it, able to understand that there could be a reason one among of these. firewall blocking, port disabled or proxy issue but not sure how to confirm it.

Please help me how to fix this issue.

Thanks,
Karunagara Pandi G

Answer (score 0):

The "Caused by" gives you the answer: the configured database host is unknown!

Either because you have a typo in the configuration ("hoost" instead of "host"), the respective machine is (was) currently offline, or the (local) DNS has (had) lost the name of the machine. Another option is that someone renamed the database host (that would be similar to the typo, only that it was not really your fault).

Determine which options (maybe there are more …) fits to your situation and fix it.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response. In my machine, i have installed sql developer and if i want to see the host name configuration of the database, where can i go and check ?

Comment: Depends on where the exception was thrown. I am not a Jenkins expert, so I cannot help you there. But SQL Developer will not help you here.